# Dependant assemblies of different version in a same project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.0, .net-assembly

Project Structure:

[image]

As the above structure defines i havea main application (DLLTestAPP) and it has reference to 2 projects App1 and App2.
Where App1 has a reference to a assembly (MyAssembly v1.0)
and App2 has reference to the same assembly but different version (Myassembly v2.0)

If i run this project it automatically picks up the latest 'MyAssembly' v2.0, i.e. under bin/release folder i only see one Myassembly file which is v2.0. Hence it breaks App1 functionality ..

But what i would like to configure DLLTestAPP is it should reference MyAssembly v1.0 and v2.0 both from a different folder while building

Could you please help?

Comment: You have two DLLs with the same name.  One is going to overwrite the other.  So inevitably somebody is going to lose.  The .NET Framework has a good solution for DLL Hell like this, you can also install them in the GAC.  Installer required.